# height: 100% not reaching to bottom of containing element

Tags: html, css

I have tried looking at similar questions, but I can't seem to find a solution. I'd appreciate it if someone could take a look here and see why the sidebar is not extending to the bottom of the content div: http://robert.io/posts/1.html

I definitely don't want to use Javascript for this. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick fix is to add these:

```css
body { background-color: #2C3B63; }
#content { background-color: white; }
```

Comment: That works, thanks! I also had to add `min-height: %100;` to `#content` to get it to look right.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. In effect you don't really want sidebar to float. So it might make sense to modify the CSS (and maybe HTML) to reflect this. But hey... if it has the desired result now, then great.

Comment: Since it's just a personal website, I'm not too concerned with best practices now. I might fiddle with it in the future to make the CSS a little nicer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Make the following CSS changes:

```
<style type="text/css">
#page {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}

#sidebar, #content {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    clear: none;
}

#sidebar {
    vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
```

Tested on Chrome 26 (OS X)

Comment: This is causing many more problems with formatting for me in Firefox. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by changing one line of code in your CSS: <strike>position: relative</strike>

```
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
}
```

But with how you have things setup, it causes your content to sit behind your sidebar. So just adjust your `margin-left` for `#content`. I plaid around with it, and looked about right around 325 (if I remember correctly).

Comment: The problem with using a `margin-left` is that it depends on how big your screen is.